# Eclipse IDE auto brackets not working correctly

Tags: java, eclipse

In Eclipse IDE, when i open curly bracket, it does not close it automatically due to another closing bracket exists. To be more clear:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    while(true) { //when i put this this curly bracket,

} // it does not put closing because of this bracket exists. 
 //It belongs 'main' but 'while' owns it.
```

I hope i described my problem clearly. I'm looking for solution.

Comment: I'm finding it gives me the matching bracket _after_ I hit the Enter key.

Comment: @FredLarson thanks for responding, i couldn't notice that. It gives me too, so my problem is solved. Thank you so much!